# SpringApplicationRunListeners v.s. ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, listener

I'm reading the source code of `SpringApplication`, and I found two kinds of `Listener`.

- There is a list of `ApplicationListner` as class field declared with

  `private List<ApplicationListener<?>> listeners`
- And in `run` method, I found a `SpringApplicationRunListeners`
  declared with

  `SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners = getRunListeners(args);`

What's the difference between them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationListner` - Interface to be implemented by application event listeners.

This might be helpful for better understanding of what is event is spring app https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

`SpringApplicationRunListener` - Listener for the `SpringApplication` `run` method. A new SpringApplicationRunListener instance will be created for each run.

Spring Boot app launches from a Java main method where you usually do something like `SpringApplication.run(...)` . Basically, you can use that interface to handle Spring Boot App bootstrap process events.